# How to extract channel names from YouTube subscription source file

Tags: grep, regex

I have an html source file of YouTube subscriptions, and want to extract just the `/user/CHANNELNAME` parts into a separate file.

The source file (`browser > youtube.com > subscriptions > manage > Ctrl+U`) has that information wrapped up into sections like this:

```
"url":"/user/CHANNELNAME","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL","rootVe":3611,"apiUrl":"/youtubei/v1/browse"
```

I'm trying to use grep -o to extract the `/user/CHANNELNAME` part, but my attempts always fall foul of the greedy *.

```
$ grep -o '/user/.*"' source
```

Results in grep matching:

**/user/CHANNELNAME","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL","rootVe":3611,"apiUrl":"/youtubei/v1/browse"**

Or:

```
$ grep -o '/user/.*,' source
```

Results in grep matching the same:

**/user/CHANNELNAME","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL","rootVe":3611,"apiUrl":"/youtubei/v1/browse"**

How do I get grep to stop at the first `"` or `,`

Comment: `grep -o '/user/.*,' source | awk -F '"' '{print $1}'`

Comment: That doesn't work, I just get pages of commas and nothing else!

Comment: Source file via Ctrl+U (so HTML) on Manage Subscriptions YouTube page (updated question for clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you want seems to be inside double quotes, if this is always the case, instead of matching any character (`.`) try matching any character but double quotes:

```
grep -o '/user/[^"]*' source
```

The `^` inverts the match. Assuming there is always a comma, you could use `[^",]` if some of the channel names aren't surrounded by double quotes

In case you are simply looking for the part after /user/, you can use the `-P` switch of grep to strip the /user/ part while still matching it:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/user/)[^",]*' source
```